# Why can I not click on this element in this code?

Tags: c#, selenium

`Actions action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement we = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label']"));

action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']"))).Click().Build().Perform();`

expect element as followings:

`< span tabindex = "-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label" style="max-width: 200px;">
    <a tabindex = "0" class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" onclick="return false">
        <img tabindex = "-1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-New_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" style="vertical-align: top;" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"> 
        <span tabindex = "-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" [enter image description here][1]style="max-width: 150px;" command="lead|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid"> 
            New
        </span>
        <div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible"> 
            Create a new Lead record. 
        </div>

    </a> 
</span>`

Note that this class `"ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label"` turns to be `"ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered"` when mouseover.

Many thanks.

Comment: Mistake of copy and paste.  Actually, there is no "." infront of //

Comment: Under span also has <a>... </a>                                                                                      <a tabindex="0" class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" onclick="return false"><img tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-New_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" style="vertical-align: top;" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"> <span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" style="max-width: 150px;" command="lead|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid"> New </span><div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible"> Create a new Lead record. </div>  </a>

Comment: Hello - and welcome to SO - please  read "How to ask a question" before: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search for the hovered element it doesn't exist.
So you need to hover element first, then you'll be able to find and click hovered element.
`action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label']"))).Build().Perform().MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']"))).Click().Build().Perform();`

Comment: Result Message: 
Test method UnitTestProject1.CRMTest.CRM_Test_in_IE threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label']

Comment: I tried below code and I see the highlight on the icon (lable + New), but Click does not perform at all.                        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']"))).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@ src='/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif']"))).Click().Build().Perform();

Comment: This code works..finally.  Thank you.      Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By. XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']"))).Click().Build().Perform(); 
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']")).Click();

Comment: I can't understand how did I help you, because your code uses other classes than mine, but I'm glad to hear that you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

In hover case first you need to moveTo That element after that you can click on it.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur element"))).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label']"))).Build().Perform();
            action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']"))).Click().Build().Perform();  and 
        Result Message: Test method UnitTestProject1.CRMTest.CRM_Test_in_IE threw exception: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label']

Comment: This code works..finally. Thank you.                                                      Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By. XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']"))).Click().Build().P‌​erform(); driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-B‌​utton ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']")).Click();